# how to make the StringListProperty's value unique in google-app-engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unique

the next code is **error**:

```
class Thread(db.Model):
  members = db.StringListProperty(unique =True)
```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is no `unique` parameter for the constructor of a property. This is why your code crashes.

There is unfortunately no built-in mechanism on the datastore level. You will need to implement that in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a single property unique to a kind and entity group by making it the entity's key_name.  The datastore will not enforce uniqueness for you in any other way.

Comment: This would mean that the value of that property could NEVER change. In this "Thread" example, I imagine the "members" would eventually change?